# "ValueError: year is out of range" with IEX Cloud API

Tags: python, pandas, api, dataframe, valueerror

I have a CSV (which I converted to a dataframe) consisting of company/stock data:

```
  Symbol  Quantity  Price  Cost      date
0    DIS         9    NaN    20  20180531
1   SBUX         5    NaN    30  20180228
2   PLOW         4    NaN    40  20180731
3   SBUX         2    NaN    50  20191130
4    DIS        11    NaN    25  20171031
```

And I am trying to use the IEX Cloud API to pull in the stock `Price` for a given `date`. And then ultimately write that to the dataframe. Per the [IEX Cloud API documentation](https://pypi.org/project/iexfinance/), I can use the `get_historical_data` function, where the 2nd argument is the `date`: `df = get_historical_data("SBUX", "20190617", close_only=True)`

Everything works fine so long as I pass in a raw date directly to the function (e.g., `20190617`), but if I try using a variable instead, I get `ValueError: year 20180531 is out of range`. I'm guessing something is wrong with the `date` format in my original CSV?

Here is my full code:

```
import os
from iexfinance.stocks import get_historical_data
import pandas as pd

os.environ['IEX_API_VERSION'] = 'iexcloud-sandbox'
os.environ['IEX_TOKEN'] = 'Tsk_5798c0ab124d49639bb1575b322841c4'

input_df = pd.read_csv("all.csv")

for index, row in input_df.iterrows():
    symbol = row['Symbol']
    date = row['date']
    temp_df = get_historical_data(symbol, date, close_only=True, output_format='pandas')
    price = temp_df['close'].values[0]

    print(temp_df)
```

*Note that this is a public token, so it's okay to use*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you called `get_historical_data("SBUX", "20190617", close_only=True)`
you passed the date as a **string**.

But when you read a DataFrame using *read_csv*, this column
(containing 8-digit strings) is converted to an **integer**.

This difference can be the source of problem.

Try 2 things:

- convert this column to string, or
- while reading the DataFrame, pass *dtype={'date': str}*,
  so that this column will be read as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine if you transform your `date` row into `datetime`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['20180531'])

pd.to_datetime(df.values[:, 0])
```

```
Out[43]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-05-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Then, your column will be correctly formatted for use elsewhere. You can insert this line below `pd.read_csv()`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: When I do ```input_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(input_df['date'])``` and print the results, I get something like: ```1970-01-01 00:00:00.020180412```, which seems incorrect?